# SQL performance by setting sendStringParametersAsUnicode =false in .NET

Tags: java, .net, sql

We migrated from Net Weaver to Tomcat for JAVA servers and during migration  the `sendStringParametersAsUnicode` parameter was not set as *false* in SQL connection URL which causes severe performance degradation.

Now we are setting `sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false` explicitly for Java.

My question is, do we need to set this parameter while connecting to SQL 2008 from .NET 4?

As far as I know it is applicable for Java drivers/engine.

Below article explains more on `sendStringParametersAsUnicode` connection parameter.

- [the article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281364/Solving-Performance-issues-in-data-migration-to-SQ)

Answer (score 2):

This parameter is needed just for JAVA Drivers and is needed just when connecting with a Java application.